# How to acess a global variable and change its value from another module

Tags: python, django

I have a global variable that is Increasing, and I wanna reset the counter from another module.

Whenever post_save signal runs, Counter variable increases and I see the number
in the terminal.

But I will call a code from another module and I want to set counter to 0, So when I call post_save signal again it starts from 0.

As I did it seems there are 2 variables.

```
counter = 0
@receiver(post_save, sender=Numbers)
def num_post(sender, **kwargs):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    dict = {}
    for object in Numbers.objects.all():
        dict[object.pk] = object.number
        print(dict)


    Group('group1').send({
        'text': json.dumps(dict)
    })
```

---

```
from .models import counter

    def ws_disconnect(message):
        global counter
        counter = 0
        print(counter)
        Group('eae').discard(message.reply_channel)
        Group('opa').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Comment: I'm going to be *that* person to tell you that you really should not be doing this. Modifying globals across files means there is a 100% guarantee of a better way to do this.

Comment: @idjaw If there is a better way please tell me.

Comment: If you are going to be modifying the state of things across modules and needing to keep track of the state, you should consider making a class and containing all your data in the instance of that class so it is easier to manage, maintain and troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes of a module object correspond to the globals inside that module. This is already familiar if you've ever said `import module; module.function()`. Well, you can set attributes in the same way.

```
from . import models
models.counter = 0
```